# PHP PDO MYSQL - Fetch where returning no results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to fetch results where a column is equal to a value in that column, my code runs with the where clause removed from the query but with it no errors are thrown but the foreach doesn't run.

```
$themes = Singlequery ('SELECT * FROM items WHERE type = :theme ORDER BY id = :id DESC LIMIT 5', 
                      array('theme' => ['theme'], 'id' => ['id']), $conn);

<?php foreach ($themes as $theme) : ?>
      <li><a href="#"><?= $theme['name']; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is my function thats **why** I have bindings;

```
function Singlequery($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);

    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: Try to debug your `Singlequery()` function using `echo $stmt->errorCode()` and `print_r($stmt->errorInfo())`. And post here results.

Comment: *"my code runs with the where clause removed from the query"* - Your query failed. *"but with it no errors are thrown"* - Are you checking for them? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parameters array is wrong, it should be:

```
array(':theme' => $theme, ':id' => $id)
```

Note the `:` in there. As well, your values are actually arrays. When PDO starts binding, it's going to be expecting strings, and finds an array, so most likely your query (if the parameters had worked in the first place),w ould be producing the equivalent of:

```
SELECT ... WHERE type = 'Array' ORDER BY id = 'id'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're binding an array.

`array('theme' => ['theme'], 'id' => ['id'])`

`['theme']` is equivalent to `array(0 => 'theme')`

Answer (score 0):

You could stay in PHP:

```
$themes = Singlequery ('SELECT * 
                        FROM items 
                        WHERE type = :theme 
                        ORDER BY id = :id DESC 
                        LIMIT 5', 
                        array('theme' => $myTheme, 
                              'id'    => $myId), 
                        $conn);

foreach ($themes as $theme) {
  echo '<li><a href="#">'.$theme['name'].'</a></li>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

You will still have to provide a value for `$myTheme` and `$myId`.